# In battery mode disable apm hard drive sleeping?

Tags: hard-drive, power-management, battery

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to disable advanced power management level up to 255 when my laptop is in battery mode. At this moment amp change it to level 1 and it's very hard to deal with. Because of the speed of discharge it won't be good for the battery-life. I tried to change it by using `hdparm` and put below configuration in `/etc/hdparm.conf`.

```
/dev/sda {
    apm = 255
    apm_battery = 255
}
```

This works when the computer starts but when the power plug is off and the system is in battery mode it changes again to level 1. How do I change it to level 255 in both power and battery mode?